# File scope variables in C++ optimised differently in gcc and clang

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, clang

I was playing around with Godbolt and I was surprised to see that the following simple C++ code had different compiled outputs on [x86-64 gcc 10.2](https://godbolt.org/z/xMETrE) and [x86-64 clang 11.0.0](https://godbolt.org/z/GKzPea) with `-O2` level optimization.

```cpp
static int x = 0;
int const y = x;

int main()
{
    x = 0; // should be optimised out?
}
```

gcc:

```
main:
        mov     DWORD PTR x[rip], 0
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
        ret
```

clang:

```
main:                                   # @main
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

Why can clang prove that `x` is unused and optimise it out but not gcc?

Comment: Because optimizers are hard to write and sometimes they really do what we want but not always?

Comment: --> https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ if there isn't already a similar report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimizers only optimize whatever got implemented into them.

In this case, I believe that Clang is correct with the optimization as the initialization in main is the very first assignment happening to a global.
This global can't be touched, as initialization of globals over multiple compilation units can't rely on globals from another compilation unit.

Since you don't initialize any other global that is changing `a`, the value was 0 before the assignment and it ain't needed.

I think this is just an edge case where the modeling of clang causes this to optimize the code. If you are using more complex code, this kind of optimizations will most likely not even be measurable.